# Pentaho data integration "get file names" not loading big list of files

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have big amount (over 200k) of pdf files in a remote drive like \remote\location. I have to read all file names from that directory and insert the file names into a database.

I have tried "get file names" step. However it is not loading the file names and the transformation is getting stopped immediately.
I have tried with smaller number of records which are in the same remote directory, but in a sub directory. it is working fine.
However when I tried for all files(including sub directories) it is crashing.  running into out of memory.  `(Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space))`

Is there a way that I can process for each 1000 files once?

Answer (score 2):

You ran out of memory. Edit the spoon.sh file and search for this line.

`PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"`

if you have 4gb of memory available you can set 2gb, (it's up to you).

`PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"`

restart your spoon and try again.

Comment: what ever size i am giving which is exceeded 1024m then it is giving me error of not able to create virtual machine, so what can i do for this?

Comment: i got my solution.. 1024 is a limitation for 32bit java.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Kettle is very memory hungry. For example, I typically need 8 GB to run a relatively long and complex process on files of just 250,000 records. So before I run kitchen or pan I always set `JAVAMAXMEM` appropriately high. You set it in units of MB, so for 4 GB you'd set

```
JAVAMAXMEM=4096 kitchen.sh ...
```

Comment: This is not the exact problem of memory.  There are large number of files. If I have to increase memory then I need to put 100GB. So, I want to run with a loop (1000 files at a time).  Please advice me on this...

Comment: in that case what I have done is wrap my kettle job in a shell script that passes a single file name as a parameter to the job and then load the file from the filename in the parameter. then i can iterate over the files in the shell script to process one at a time (or more than one at a time, if you so desire).